# How to intigrate multiple image uploader in a custom post type

Tags: images

[image]

How can i add this type of field in the custom post type

Comment: You are using plugin for multiple image upload?

Comment: Thanku @ Bindiya Patoliya , but actly i want to learn so  that , so any tutorial link, no i m not using any plugin..

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: I design my own custom theme. 
and their i intigrate  this code for the custom post type..


function ajit_create_post_type() {
$labels = array(
'name' => __( 'Open House' ),
'singular_name' => __( 'Open House' ),
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'has_archive' => true,
'public' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'supports' => array(
'title',
'editor',
'excerpt',
'thumbnail',
),
);
register_post_type( 'Open_house', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'ajit_create_post_type' );

Comment: give me your multi upload code

Comment: No i dont have any code yet, but i want to use this on my themes,

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) - its very easy to use and you can call any of it's values pretty simply using a ACF short-code like `<?php the_field('image1'); ?>`

It works with any post types and lets you customise which fields are shown on each type.

If you are looking to learn how and implement it all yourself then make sure you:

1. Have a bit of time, and patience
2. A local test server (such as MAMP or WAMP) to play around on without breaking your website.
3. [Give this website a read](http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-meta-boxes-guide/) and of course [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

## EDIT

Preview of ACF image boxes

[image: Preview of ACF image uploader]

WITH IMAGE

[image: Preview of uploaded]

Comment: Thanx @Bysander  
Thanx for the help,
i will try near about 4 time but i failed,
to implement.
http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-meta-boxes-guide/
This link is really helpfull Thanx for the link.
i will try more...

Thanx..

Comment: I would recommend using Advanced Custom Fields - details above - very simple yet powerful plugin that will save you a lot of time adding your custom meta data to posts. The link was to help you if you wanted to code it yourself but can be a bit to get your head round.